# ubuntu 20.04 cannot login ubuntu Single Sign-On Account "Something went wrong, please try again"

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-one

In Ubuntu 20.04, I cannot login Ubuntu Single Sign-On Account: "Something went wrong, please try again"

On my laptop I have tried many times but still can't login, but when I use my desktop computer I can login.

[image: Error connecting to Ubuntu Sign-On Account]

Comment: Are you able to log in at https://login.ubuntu.com/ ?  if not, you need to create an account for it to work.

Comment: Of course I have, if I don't have it, I'm sure the message is email and password error

Comment: Same problem here - ever get this fixed?

Comment: Even in Ubuntu 21.10 the error is still there. I'm unable to login in my Ubuntu Single Sign-On account from Ubuntu, but I can from the website.